# Clone an Object With Given Properties Only

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to clone an object only from specified properties. The new object must contain only properties specified in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
function cloneWithProperties(obj, props) {
    let retObj = {};

  if (!props) { // if no props are specified
      throw new Error('Props must be specified');
  }  

  props.forEach(function(element) {
    retObj[element] = obj[element];
  }, this);

  return retObj;
}

let old = {
    name: 'clinton',
    age: 10,
    salary: 5000
}

let n = cloneWithProperties(old, ['name']);

console.log(n); // { name: 'clinton' }
```